# Augmenting «$\Bbb Z[x]$ f.g. $\Rightarrow x$ integral» for ${\frak p}[x]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

In KCd's [blurb on ideal factorization](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf), page 5:

$\hskip 0.3in$ [image: blurb]

The situation is this: $K$ is a number field, ${\cal O}_K$ its ring of integers, ${\frak p}\triangleleft{\cal O}_K$ a prime ideal, $x\in K$.

We assume $x \frak p\subseteq p$ and want to derive from this $x\in{\cal O}_K$. Based on my reading of the blurb above, I tried to run through the argument for how $\Bbb Z[x]$ f.g. over $\Bbb Z$ implies $x$ is integral, but in ${\frak p}[x]$:

> Let ${\frak p}[x]$ be the set of all ${\frak p}$-coefficient polynomials in $x$. Then ${\frak p}[x]=\frak p$ since $x\frak p\subseteq\frak p$. Thus the non-unital polynomial ring ${\frak p}[x]$ is a free $\Bbb Z$-module, and we have a basis $P_1(x),\cdots,P_n(x)$. Let $M\ge\deg P_1,\cdots,\deg P_m$ and write $x^M=c_1P_1(x)+\cdots+c_mP_m(x)$ with $c_1,\cdots,c_m\in\frak p$; this exhibits an explicit integral relation that $x$ satisfies.

The problem is, in order to write $x^M$ using the basis we would need $x^M\in{\frak p}[x]$, but $x^M$ has coefficient $1\not\in\frak p$ so it's not automatic that $x^M\in{\frak p}[x]$ and this argument falls flat.

Is there something the author has in mind that I am not getting? Either way, is there a way to augment the usual proof of $\Bbb Z[x]$ f.g. $\Rightarrow x$ integral to this situation to show $x\in{\cal O}_K$? In a different direction: as $\frak p$ is f.g. we know that $x$ acts by an integer matrix - is ${\rm End}_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z^n)$ is integrally closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer relatively quickly in Stewart's *Algebraic Number Theory* pg $109$.

Suppose $\theta{\frak a}\subseteq{\frak a}$ for some ideal ${\frak a}=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$. Then

$$\begin{cases} a_1\theta & = b_{11}a_1+\cdots+b_{1n}a_n \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ a_n\theta & =b_{n1}a_1+\cdots+b_{nn}a_n\end{cases}\implies \begin{pmatrix}b_{11}-\theta & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1n} \\ b_{21} & b_{22}-\theta & \cdots & b_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ b_{n1} & b_{n2} & \cdots & b_{nn}-\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix}=0.$$

Thus $\det(B-\theta I_{n\times n})=0$ where $B$ is an integer matrix, which is an integral relation in $\theta$.

I prefer the "write $x^M$ in the basis" approach to proving integrality from $\Bbb Z[x]$ f.g., but it's the determinant version of the argument that needs to be used in this case.

Comment: Amusingly I just now found it on pg $4$ of Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory*.